# Google API: Get another user's email address by email alias

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api, google-people-api, google-calendar-api

We'd like to retrieve from Google another user's primary email address based on an email alias.

Note that it's not for the same user that authorized the app with Google OAuth but for another user in the organization (otherwise the Google People API would be handy).

We saw that this is possible using the Admin Directory API but this API is only accessible to Admins of the organization and we need to support regular users.

**Background**

When requesting information about another user's calendar using Google Calendar API - only the primary email address can be used, email aliases are not recognized. The problem is that many times users use an email alias and not their primary email address.

---

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service account to access most of the data on the domain which includes data from the directory.